# Python Virtual Environment changes python binary version (local to global) if I move out of Scripts directory

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have activated my virtual environment created by `virtualenv` using Scripts/activate on `Windows 7`.

If I run Python from here (`Scripts`), I can access 3.67 version, the local version.

However if I cd into another directory, and call `python`, I open up python2.7 which is a version I have installed on my PC.

Is this normal behavior? Do I need to call the full path to the python binary if I want to use it outside of the `Scripts` directory.

I need to move to another directory, because I have to call `jupyter notebook` from that directory to gain access to the notebooks in that specific directory.

Comment: once you've activated your `virtualenv`, `python` and the environment should behave the same in any directory. From within the other directory you `cd` to, check the command `WHERE python` should still point to your `virtualenv`'s `venv/Scripts/python.exe`

Comment: Also, you should not need to run python scripts within the `venv/Scripts` directory, the `Scripts` directory is for the executables to manage the virtual environment, you should not need put any of your python scripts inside (or run any scripts from within) that directory, other than explicitly running `Scripts/activate`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you so much for your comments.  When running the command WHERE python, it's pointing to the system installation instead of the local virtual environment.  Is there a way to change this? This is the first time I am running into this error. I would like to keep this environment as it took a bit to get some frameworks installed and working properly.